# How to pass array in db using laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying array data send in db but I got error
here is my function where i send data in db

```
 public function create(Request $request)
  {
      $tags = explode(",", $request->labels);
      $posts = new Post();
    $posts->user_id = $request->id;
    $posts->title = $request->title;
    $posts->description = $request->description;
    $tags = explode(",", $request->labels);

    $posts->tags = $tags; // error is here in this line
    $posts->save();
      return redirect()->back()->with('message' , 'post created!!!!!');

  }
```

Comment: Please share the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$posts->tags` is related - i.e Post hasMany Tag, Tag belongsToMany Post - then you should be able to attach the tags to the post like so:

```
$posts->tags()->attach($tags);
$posts->save();
```